# Getting a Facebook ID from an order_id through Graph API -- occasional mangled results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been working on a reporting script, where part of it involves getting the Facebook ID associated with purchases pulled from reports generated through the Payments Reports API.

The reports generate beautifully, and I then am able to throw any order_id at Graph API to get the Facebook ID:

https://graph.facebook.com/{order_id}?access_token={app_access_token}

returns:

```
{
  "id": "{order_id}"
  "from":
  "to":
  "amount":
  "status": ""
  "application":
  "country":
  "created_time":
  "updated_time":
}
```

According to documentation, the 'from' section is the Facebook ID associated with the account.

On occasions, I sometimes will get a long string of letters instead of an ID.

I have been having trouble finding more information in interpreting these -- my suspicion is that these are purchases that no longer are associated with an active Facebook ID, but really unsure here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked - it doesn't seem to be in the API documentation (will try to see why that is), but...

This is expected if the user who made the order has subsequently removed or blocked your app - (i.e if the user who made that order is no longer a user of your app.) In this case you receive an encrypted form of the uid (which should be consistent across all orders that particular user made in your app)